# Java VisualVM does not show/list my tomcat java process

Tags: java, profiling, jmx, visualvm, jvisualvm

I am using `jdk64` and my java version is `1.6.0_24`. I am running both (Tomcat java process and VisualVM) processes as Administrator on Windows Server 2008.

Tomcat is running with `-Xmx7196m`, where as `jvisualvm` is running with `-Xms24m` and `-Xmx256m`. Could this be the cause?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `Java VisualVM does not show/list my tomcat java process`

Comment: Under the `Local` node in the `Applications` view, my process is not listed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add the `JMX` parameters to enable the `JMX` connection to your application, so add the following parameters:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8484
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Then You need to add your tomcat process manually, So `right click on you localhost node -> Add JMX Connection -> type your port -> OK`.

Your tomcat process will be listed in under localhost node.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. By default if I capture heap dump they go to `C:\Users\kuldeep\AppData\Local\Temp\visualvm.dat\localhost_PID` directory. Can I change this location? I don't have enough space in my `C:\` drive.

Comment: I used `jvisualvm.exe --userdir "E:\VisualVM_userdir"` to change `userdir`. That would enable capturing Snapshot to `userdir`. Would it also save head dump in there?

Comment: I closed and relaunched VisualVM and tomcat both. And now when I try to `Add JMX Connection` on same port it gives the error: **jmx connection service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8484/jmxrmi already exists as localhost:8484**. But how do I open the existing one?

Comment: Look under your localhost node, you'll find the tomcat process, you don't have to add it each time.

Comment: No, it is not there for sure. Additionally I see `Computing description...` in the bottom right corner of VisualVM going on for quiet some time.

Comment: Restarting the m/c and re-launching the tomcat & jvisualvm solved the issue.

Comment: @KuldeepJain where did you add the parameters in the answer ?

Comment: @mounaim You need to add those parameters as VM args while starting your application that you want to monitor  `java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5000
     -jar MyApplication.jar`                                                                                         You can refer to this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason VisualVM cannot find Java because of OS process privileges.

If you start VisualVM with the same user & security context as Java app you will see it: VisualVM will gain access to sockets, `/proc` fs, etc...

To workaround the OS security stuff you can expose your Java app via JMX appending sys props:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=[...PORT...]
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
```

`java.rmi.server.hostname` is an important security measure to prevent connection to your app JMX from outside. If you need a remote connection just pass the port with *SSH tunnel*.

Answer (score 0):

Our application server is JBOSS 6.1.0.final and our server itself is not starting on adding these lines to the run.conf.bat file
`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8484
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false`

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question. If it is an answer can you please elaborate?