# Java VisualVM to get HeapDump from tomcat but Tomcat is not listed under local applications

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory, jvisualvm

I am trying to diagnose a possible memory leak issue. The application is behaving very slow. Just by increasing the permgen size will only temporarily solve the issue. I want to garbage collect the unwanted classloader space. so, I need to get a heap dump of tomcat server.

This is the issue from my tomcat logs:

The web application [/] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@1dfd670]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [false]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

To add tomcat to the applications in Java visualvm, there are some steps mentioned in this question.

[Java VisualVM does not show/list my tomcat java process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294114/java-visualvm-does-not-show-list-my-tomcat-java-process)

where should I be adding this in the application? It is a war file that I have deployed in the client's server. I cannot create a new war file now.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8484
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Comment: lots of things that may be missing. Ports blocked or jstatd not running. Google for remote VM monitoring with visual VM. Also if there is a firewall in between you may need to check out "VisualVm using socks poxy" in google.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enable it on your server, have a look at the print i took for you:

[image]

If you are deploying it on client, you will have to pass it through JAVA_OPTS.

Linux example:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Detc etc..."
```

Windows example:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Detc etc..."
```

Inside the arguments, you need to add these:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8484
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Check if the port is not been used.

Then you need to configure your JMX, here is the oficial tutorial, it is kind of simple: http://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html

Comment: do you mean that I have to make the setting changes and then redeploy the war file? Your screenshot is from eclipse, I guess. I have the war file deployed in my client's tomcat server. My current situation, I cannot create a new war.

Comment: Yes, the screenshoot is ilustrative, you will have to redeploy it after you set this new JAVA_OPTS