# visualvm/jvisualvm: not supported for this JVM

Tags: java, service, jvm, visualvm, jvisualvm

I wanted to monitor the JVM of wildfly running as service with jvisualvm/visualvm but I fail to do this. I tried the following things:

- setting the %TMP% and %TEMP% to C:\Windows\Temp (wildfly console
  tells me this for java.io.tmpdir)
- running a console with sysinternals
  pstools as system account: psexec -i -s cmd.exe and started visualvm
  from within this new console (checked that the temp folders are
  correctly set).

In both cases under local applications the process of wildfly was listed but visualvm only told me "not supported for this jvm".

As soon as I run wildfly from the cli, visualvm has no problems and shows me everything. There is only the jdk from oracle installed (with the corresponding jre).

How can I monitor the process of wildfly running as service (local system account)? Why is it not working with the solutions above?

Thanks a lot (for reading)

Comment: Check this answer >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294114/java-visualvm-does-not-show-list-my-tomcat-java-process/22295237#22295237

Answer (score 3):

Thank you Salah

With your hint (local JMX connection) I've managed to make it work by using the following command for visualvm (no change of TMP/TEMP variables in cmd):

```
visualvm.exe -cp:a "<path-to-wildfly>\bin\client\jboss-client.jar"
```

and adding the path to the jmx console (don't forget to set the username/pw for the admin gui)

```
service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://localhost:9990
```

Comment: Confirming this for *JBoss EAP 6.3*. Notes: 1) "don't forget to set the username/pw for the admin gui" - this doesn't seem to be necessary for local JMX connections, 2) one may use `service:jmx:remoting-jmx://localhost:9999` instead of `service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://localhost:9990`.